# Jolt transformation with array

Tags: json, jolt

I have input JSON as

```json
{
  "eventTime" : "2024-01-17T15:10:06.858",
  "groupArticleNumber" : "FT6559",
  "groupModelNumber" : "FRX88",
  "productDescriptionEN" : "ESTRO 19 JSYY",
  "subBrand" : "1",
  "brand" : "11",
  "businessSegment" : "104",
  "salesLine" : "L84",
  "materialComposition" : [ "100% PET-REC", "100% PET-DAT" ],
  "mainMaterialFlag" : [ true, false ],
  "productDescEN" : "ESTRO 19 JSYY",
  "colorwayShortDescEN" : "TMLGBL/WHITE",
  "keyCategory" : "00095",
  "ageGroup" : "J",
  "gender" : "M",
  "genderAge" : "16",
  "genderAgeMain" : "Kids",
  "articleLifeCycle" : "50",
  "sizePage" : "J4",
  "articleCreationSeason" : "20201",
  "articleActiveSeason" : "20242",
  "rmhProductDivision" : "2",
  "rmhProductType" : "30",
  "rmhCategory" : "09",
  "retailClass" : "12309",
  "retailSubClass" : "1230930",
  "retailDepartment" : "12",
  "retailSubDepartment" : "123",
  "sourcingSizeCode3" : [ "190", "180" ]
}
```

and i want output like

```json
[
  {
    "eventTime": "2024-01-17T15:10:06.858",
    "groupArticleNumber": "GI7343",
    "sourcingSizeCode3": "190",
    "productDescEN": "A.RDY UPF LS P",
    "colorwayShortDescEN": "NHLSJS/WHTMEL/BLACK",
    "keyCategory": "00056",
    "groupModelNumber": "FRX88",
    "productDescriptionEN": "ESTRO 19 JSYY",
    "retailClass": "12309",
    "retailSubClass": "1230930",
    "retailDepartment": "12",
    "retailSubDepartment": "123",
    "rmhProductDivision": "2",
    "subBrand": "1",
    "brand": "11",
    "rmhCategory": "09",
    "businessSegment": "104",
    "ageGroup": "J",
    "gender": "M",
    "genderAge": "16",
    "genderAgeMain": "Kids",
    "articleLifeCycle": "50",
    "sizePage": "J4",
    "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC",
    "mainMaterialFlag": true,
    "articleCreationSeason": "20201",
    "articleActiveSeason": "20242",
    "salesLine": "L84",
    "rmhProductType": "30"
  },
  {
    "eventTime": "2024-01-17T15:10:06.858",
    "groupArticleNumber": "GI7343",
    "sourcingSizeCode3": "180",
    "productDescEN": "A.RDY UPF LS P",
    "colorwayShortDescEN": "NHLSJS/WHTMEL/BLACK",
    "keyCategory": "00056",
    "groupModelNumber": "FRX88",
    "productDescriptionEN": "ESTRO 19 JSYY",
    "retailClass": "12309",
    "retailSubClass": "1230930",
    "retailDepartment": "12",
    "retailSubDepartment": "123",
    "rmhProductDivision": "2",
    "subBrand": "1",
    "brand": "11",
    "rmhCategory": "09",
    "businessSegment": "104",
    "ageGroup": "J",
    "gender": "M",
    "genderAge": "16",
    "genderAgeMain": "Kids",
    "articleLifeCycle": "50",
    "sizePage": "J4",
    "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC",
    "mainMaterialFlag": true,
    "articleCreationSeason": "20201",
    "articleActiveSeason": "20242",
    "salesLine": "L84",
    "rmhProductType": "30"
  },
  {
    "eventTime": "2024-01-17T15:10:06.858",
    "groupArticleNumber": "GI7343",
    "sourcingSizeCode3": "190",
    "productDescEN": "A.RDY UPF LS P",
    "colorwayShortDescEN": "NHLSJS/WHTMEL/BLACK",
    "keyCategory": "00056",
    "groupModelNumber": "FRX88",
    "productDescriptionEN": "ESTRO 19 JSYY",
    "retailClass": "12309",
    "retailSubClass": "1230930",
    "retailDepartment": "12",
    "retailSubDepartment": "123",
    "rmhProductDivision": "2",
    "subBrand": "1",
    "brand": "11",
    "rmhCategory": "09",
    "businessSegment": "104",
    "ageGroup": "J",
    "gender": "M",
    "genderAge": "16",
    "genderAgeMain": "Kids",
    "articleLifeCycle": "50",
    "sizePage": "J4",
    "materialComposition": "100% PET-DAT",
    "mainMaterialFlag": false,
    "articleCreationSeason": "20201",
    "articleActiveSeason": "20242",
    "salesLine": "L84",
    "rmhProductType": "30"
  },
  {
    "eventTime": "2024-01-17T15:10:06.858",
    "groupArticleNumber": "GI7343",
    "sourcingSizeCode3": "180",
    "productDescEN": "A.RDY UPF LS P",
    "colorwayShortDescEN": "NHLSJS/WHTMEL/BLACK",
    "keyCategory": "00056",
    "groupModelNumber": "FRX88",
    "productDescriptionEN": "ESTRO 19 JSYY",
    "retailClass": "12309",
    "retailSubClass": "1230930",
    "retailDepartment": "12",
    "retailSubDepartment": "123",
    "rmhProductDivision": "2",
    "subBrand": "1",
    "brand": "11",
    "rmhCategory": "09",
    "businessSegment": "104",
    "ageGroup": "J",
    "gender": "M",
    "genderAge": "16",
    "genderAgeMain": "Kids",
    "articleLifeCycle": "50",
    "sizePage": "J4",
    "materialComposition": "100% PET-DAT",
    "mainMaterialFlag": false,
    "articleCreationSeason": "20201",
    "articleActiveSeason": "20242",
    "salesLine": "L84",
    "rmhProductType": "30"
  }
]
```

need jolt spec for same

i tried this spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "value": {
        "metadata": {
          "eventTime": "eventTime"
        },
        "payload": {
          "productPrimaryData": {
            "key": {
              "groupArticleNumber": "groupArticleNumber",
              "groupModelNumber": "groupModelNumber"
            },
            "model": {
              "productDescriptionEN": "productDescriptionEN",
              "subBrand": "subBrand",
              "brand": "brand",
              "businessSegment": "businessSegment"
            },
            "modelSeason": {
              "salesLine": "salesLine"
            },
            "articleSeason": {
              "articleMainMaterial": {
                "*": {
                  "materialComposition": "materialComposition",
                  "mainMaterialFlag": "mainMaterialFlag"
                }
              }
            },
            "article": {
              "productDescEN": "productDescEN",
              "colorwayShortDescEN": "colorwayShortDescEN",
              "keyCategory": "keyCategory",
              "ageGroup": "ageGroup",
              "gender": "gender",
              "genderAge": "genderAge",
              "genderAgeMain": "genderAgeMain",
              "articleLifeCycle": "articleLifeCycle",
              "sizePage": "sizePage",
              "articleCreationSeason": "articleCreationSeason",
              "articleActiveSeason": "articleActiveSeason",
              "rmh": {
                "*": {
                  "rmhProductDivision": "rmhProductDivision",
                  "rmhProductType": "rmhProductType",
                  "rmhCategory": "rmhCategory",
                  "retailClass": "retailClass",
                  "retailSubClass": "retailSubClass",
                  "retailDepartment": "retailDepartment",
                  "retailSubDepartment": "retailSubDepartment"
                }
              },
              "articleSize": {
                "*": {
                  "sourcingSizeCode3": "sourcingSizeCode3"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

but not working

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you want to restructure the Json since its not clear from just providing the output. For example, there are 3 arrays: materialComposition, mainMaterialFlag  & sourcingSizeCode3 so do you want all kind of combination or you want one array to drive the combination while the other is matched based on index? Its not clear. Also in your Jolt spec you are using fields and objects that doesnt seem to be found in the Input like payload, key , model ,article ...etc. either your input is incorrect or its missing some other data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following shift transformation specs :

```json
[
  { // group by two types of arrays and objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "Others.&",
      "*ateria*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "x[&1].&2"
        }
      },
      "sourcingSizeCode3": {
        "*": {
          "@": "y[&1].&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // multiplex the arrays "x" vs. "y" through use of @1 representation
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Others": "&",
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@1": "&2&1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Others": "&",
      "x*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&1_&(2,1).&"
        }
      },
      "y*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&(2,1)_&1.&" // the reversely tiled with respect to the upper identifiers  
                             // nested within "x*" object representation
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // separate "Others" object vs. array
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Others": "&",
      "*": "arr"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "arr": {
        "*": {
          "@2,Others": { "*": "[&1].&" }, // go two levels up the tree to grab the values from the "arr" array
          "*": "[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: It worked very well .Thank you so much @Barbaros Özhan

Answer (score 0):

```
this is my input json `{
   "key":"FRX88_FT6559_20222",
   "value":{
      "metadata":{
         "eventVersion":"SPMXML4_3Out.xsd",
         "eventSource":"GRPSPM",
         "eventName":"ProductPrimary",
         "eventTime":"2024-01-17T15:10:06.858"
      },
      "payload":{
         "header":{
            "sender":"GRPSPM",
            "sequenceNumber":"spm_product_20240117155702_00001",
            "priority":"2",
            "publishingType":"PS",
            "messageType":"Product",
            "targetGroup":"ALL",
            "xsdVersion":"SPMXML4_3Out.xsd"
         },
         "productPrimaryData":{
            "changeFlag":{
               "articleChange":true,
               "articleSeasonChange":false,
               "modelChange":true,
               "modelSeasonChange":false
            },
            "key":{
               "groupArticleNumber":"FT6559",
               "groupModelNumber":"FRX88",
               "seasonCode":"20222"
            },
            "model":{
               "altModelNumber":"MS908046",
               "modelFamily":null,
               "activity":"High performance football jersey for match day",
               "inspiration":"Plain & embellishment-friendly design",
               "uniqueSellingProposition":null,
               "studs":null,
               "closure":"00",
               "consumerFit":"01",
               "branding":"Flat heat-transferred BoS",
               "lining":"000",
               "neckLine":"002",
               "shoulderStrap":null,
               "braStyle":null,
               "fabricWeightPurpose":"51% PES/49% REC.PES; Solid; 123 G/SQM; Hydrophilic (midori); AEROREADY, ClimaLite, Midori adi (hydrophilic finish)",
               "inseamShortLength":"Standard",
               "sustainabilityEthics":"007",
               "originalModelNumber":"FRX88",
               "licensedVendor":null,
               "vendorModelNumber":null,
               "workingModelNumber":"S1906GHTM400Y",
               "macroModelCode":null,
               "productDescriptionEN":"ESTRO 19 JSYY",
               "modelLongDescEN":"Estro 19 Jersey Youth",
               "consumerFacingProdName":"ESTRO 19 JERSEY",
               "brandGroup":"10",
               "brand":"11",
               "sportsCategory":"06",
               "productDivision":"2",
               "productGroup":"28",
               "productSet":"20",
               "productType":"16",
               "ageGroup":"J",
               "gender":"M",
               "genderAge":"16",
               "genderAgeMain":"Kids",
               "corporateMarketingLine":"98",
               "categoryMarketingLine":"197",
               "techConcept":"00341",
               "techComponent":null,
               "icgsCode":"25",
               "subBrand":"1",
               "businessSegment":"104",
               "keyCategory":"00095",
               "devOrganization":"T001",
               "devLocation":"10",
               "upperMainMaterial":null,
               "liningMainMaterial":null,
               "inSoleMainMaterial":null,
               "outSoleMainMaterial":null,
               "quantityUnit":"01",
               "outPackageQuantity":"60",
               "toeStackHeightMm":"0",
               "midSoleOffsetMm":"0",
               "heelStackHeightMm":"0",
               "modelCreationSeason":"20191",
               "modelActiveSeason":"20251",
               "modelLifecycle":"50",
               "modelLifecycleStatusDate":{
                  "value":"20190603",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "modelSourceSystem":"FLXAAG",
               "arch":null,
               "braRemovablePadding":null,
               "shoeType":null,
               "surface":null,
               "waistRise":"000",
               "materialTechnology":"02",
               "sizePage":"J4",
               "sourceSizeScale":"T6",
               "sourcingSampleSizeCode2":"27",
               "sourcingSampleSizeCode3":"540",
               "outsoleToolingNumber":null,
               "upperToolingNumber":null,
               "midsoleToolingNumber":null,
               "baseUnit":"PC",
               "targetMaterialCode":"005",
               "targetSourceCode":"3",
               "targetMaterialTechnology":"33",
               "allocCategoryCode":"0",
               "productSpeciality":"1",
               "productDimensionUom":"6",
               "length":"0",
               "width":"0",
               "height":"0",
               "productDimensionUov":"23",
               "volume":"0",
               "weight":"0",
               "featuresAndBenefits":null,
               "manufacturingType":null,
               "manufacturingCapability":"0",
               "constructionType":"1",
               "productFit":null,
               "boxLabelCategory":null,
               "managementBrand":"11",
               "materialConceptDesc":null,
               "franchiseCode":"000",
               "franchiseInspiredFamily":"000",
               "franchiseIteration":"000",
               "intendedUse":"01",
               "last":null,
               "modelPocketDetails":null
            },
            "modelSeason":{
               "salesLine":"L84",
               "sizeCategory":[
                  "003~009~012"
               ],
               "modelProductRelationShip":null,
               "salesRegion":"04~05~06~07",
               "devType":"CO",
               "targetConsumer":"00",
               "firstExFactoryDate":{
                  "value":"20220315",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "lastExFactoryDate":{
                  "value":"20221115",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "specialUsage":null,
               "sourceSizeList":"480~180~360~560~520~540~230~500~355~200~580~345~340~190~210~220~350",
               "marketingForecast":"90000",
               "placeholderStyleCount":1,
               "productPlaceholder":false,
               "retailIntroDate":{
                  "value":"20220601",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "retailExitDate":{
                  "value":"20221130",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "prodLifecycleSeasonStatus":"50",
               "designer":"Junyent, Pau",
               "developer":"Rudolph, Katharina",
               "loDeveloper":"Nguyen, Yuuna",
               "productManager":"Frasch, Lukas",
               "cadPatternMaker":"Nikolic, Natascha",
               "quarterCode":"34",
               "timelineCode":"1",
               "targetFob":2.12,
               "targetFobCurrency":"USD",
               "targetRecRetailPrice":15,
               "targetRecRetailPriceCurrency":"EUR",
               "secondTargetRecRetailPrice":0,
               "secondTargetRecRetailPriceCurrency":null,
               "modelSeasonStatus":"1",
               "directDev":"2",
               "logoId":null,
               "transportationLeadTime":"7",
               "rangePlanId":null,
               "rangePlanTitle":null,
               "dropDate":null,
               "modelCarriedOverFrom":"20221",
               "speedRelevant":true
            },
            "articleSeason":{
               "salesLine":"L84",
               "targetConsumer":"00",
               "salesRegion":"04~05~06~07",
               "developmentType":"CO",
               "distributionChannel":null,
               "specialUsage":"00",
               "productLine":"773",
               "firstExFactoryDate":{
                  "value":"20220315",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "lastExFactoryDate":{
                  "value":"20221115",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "productionLeadTime":45,
               "retailIntroDate":{
                  "value":"20220601",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "retailExitDate":{
                  "value":"20221130",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "prodLifecycleSeasonStatus":"50",
               "purchaseOrderMinQty":100,
               "quarterCode":34,
               "timelineCode":"1",
               "targetFob":2.12,
               "targetFobCurrency":"USD",
               "targetRecRetailPrice":15,
               "targetRecRetailPriceCurrency":"EUR",
               "secTargetRecRetailPrice":0,
               "secTargetRecRetailPriceCurrency":null,
               "articleMarketingForecast":"0",
               "articleMainMaterial":[
                  {
                     "materialRefNumber":"70019568",
                     "colorOverwriteInd":true,
                     "materialSupplier":"30",
                     "construction":"Doubleknit",
                     "technology":"02",
                     "fiberTextPosition":"MAIN MATERIAL - 78",
                     "materialComposition":"100% PET-REC",
                     "mainMaterialFlag":true
                  },
                   {
                     "materialRefNumber":"70019568",
                     "colorOverwriteInd":true,
                     "materialSupplier":"30",
                     "construction":"Doubleknit",
                     "technology":"02",
                     "fiberTextPosition":"MAIN MATERIAL - 88",
                     "materialComposition":"100% PET-DAT",
                     "mainMaterialFlag":false
                  }
               ],
               "buyReadyDateDeveloper":{
                  "value":"20220117",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "buyReadySetDate":{
                  "value":"20220113",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "revisedBuyReadySetDate":null,
               "articleSeasonStatus":"1",
               "seasonState":"H",
               "smuCustomer":null,
               "colorwayDelayReason":null,
               "transportationLeadTime":"7",
               "designer":"Junyent, Pau",
               "developer":"Rudolph, Katharina",
               "loDeveloper":"TBA",
               "productManager":"Frasch, Lukas",
               "directDev":"2",
               "seasonalArticleText":null,
               "colorDesigner":null,
               "materialWayType":null,
               "productTestManager":null,
               "testLevel":null,
               "dropDate":null,
               "articleCarriedOverFrom":"20221",
               "priceBand":"01",
               "mandatoryRangeCode":"00000",
               "speedPropositionCode":"00000",
               "washCareInstructions":null
            },
            "article":{
               "altArticleNumber":null,
               "originalArticleNumber":"FT6559",
               "vendorArticleNumber":null,
               "baseArticleNumber":null,
               "articleType":"01",
               "productDescEN":"ESTRO 19 JSYY",
               "colorwayName":"team light blue/white",
               "colorwayShortDescEN":"TMLGBL/WHITE",
               "colorwayLongDescEN":"TMLGBL/WHITE",
               "color1":"ADA3",
               "color2":"001A",
               "color3":null,
               "color4":null,
               "secondaryColorwayDescEN":null,
               "nrfColorCode":null,
               "alternateColorCode":null,
               "graphicCode":null,
               "graphicDesc":null,
               "ageGroup":"J",
               "gender":"M",
               "genderAge":"16",
               "genderAgeMain":"Kids",
               "corporateMarketingLine":"98",
               "categoryMarketingLine":"197",
               "techConcept":[
                  "00341"
               ],
               "devOrganization":"T001",
               "devLocation":"10",
               "subBrand":"1",
               "businessSegment":"104",
               "keyCategory":"00095",
               "pictogramCompositionCode":"XXXXXXXXX",
               "upperMainMaterial":null,
               "liningMainMaterial":null,
               "innerSoleMainMaterial":null,
               "outerSoleMainMaterial":null,
               "articleCreationSeason":"20201",
               "articleActiveSeason":"20242",
               "articleLifeCycle":"50",
               "articleLifeCycleStatusDate":{
                  "value":"20190603",
                  "format":"yyyyMMdd"
               },
               "articleSourceSystem":"FLXAAG",
               "sizePage":"J4",
               "sourcingSizeScale":"T6",
               "sourcingSampleSizeCode2":"27",
               "sourcingSampleSizeCode3":"540",
               "productFit":null,
               "orderLockedIndicator":false,
               "materialWayId":"JZF0GELBADXBNO2L",
               "marketingActivationDueDate":null,
               "targetRetailExitSeason":"20271",
               "imageConfidential":"N",
               "imageLaunchDate":null,
               "graphicPattern":[
                  "000"
               ],
               "articleDescMl":[
                  {
                     "languageCode":"01",
                     "articleDescription":"ESTRO 19 JSYY"
                  },
                  {
                     "languageCode":"02",
                     "articleDescription":"ESTRO 19 JSYY"
                  },
                  {
                     "languageCode":"03",
                     "articleDescription":"ESTRO 19 JSYY"
                  },
                  {
                     "languageCode":"04",
                     "articleDescription":"ESTRO 19 JSYY"
                  },
                  {
                     "languageCode":"05",
                     "articleDescription":"ESTRO 19 JSYY"
                  },
                  {
                     "languageCode":"06",
                     "articleDescription":"ESTRO 19 JSYY"
                  }
               ],
               "colorwayDescMl":[
                  {
                     "languageCode":"01",
                     "colorwayShortDesc":"TMLGBL/WHITE",
                     "colorwayLongDesc":"TMLGBL/WHITE"
                  },
                  {
                     "languageCode":"02",
                     "colorwayShortDesc":"TMLGBL/WHITE",
                     "colorwayLongDesc":"TMLGBL/WHITE"
                  },
                  {
                     "languageCode":"03",
                     "colorwayShortDesc":"TMLGBL/BLANC",
                     "colorwayLongDesc":"TMLGBL/BLANC"
                  },
                  {
                     "languageCode":"04",
                     "colorwayShortDesc":"TMLGBL/BLANCO",
                     "colorwayLongDesc":"TMLGBL/BLANCO"
                  },
                  {
                     "languageCode":"05",
                     "colorwayShortDesc":"TMLGBL/BRANCO",
                     "colorwayLongDesc":"TMLGBL/BRANCO"
                  },
                  {
                     "languageCode":"06",
                     "colorwayShortDesc":"TMLGBL/WHITE",
                     "colorwayLongDesc":"TMLGBL/WHITE"
                  }
               ],
               "articleLabel":[
                  {
                     "label":"ATACA",
                     "labelCount":1
                  },
                  {
                     "label":"ASSMC",
                     "labelCount":1
                  }
               ],
               "articleComposition":[
                  {
                     "animalType":null,
                     "importCountry":"000",
                     "customsCompTextEN":"100% PET-REC",
                     "pictogramCompTextEN":null,
                     "protectedAnimalInd":null
                  }
               ],
               "articleCustomsBti":null,
               "articleBrandPartner":[
                  {
                     "brandPartner":"00000",
                     "brandPartnerPriorityInd":false
                  }
               ],
               "articleTagsInformation":[
                  {
                     "tags":"00049"
                  }
               ],
               "articleSize":[
                  {
                     "sourcingSizeCode2":"63",
                     "sourcingSizeCode3":"190",
                     "feasibilityIndicator":true
                  },
                  {
                     "sourcingSizeCode2":"62",
                     "sourcingSizeCode3":"180",
                     "feasibilityIndicator":true
                  }
               ],
               "rmh":[
                  {
                     "rmhMarketingDivision":"1",
                     "rmhProductDivision":"2",
                     "rmhGender":"3",
                     "rmhCategory":"09",
                     "rmhProductType":"30",
                     "retailDepartment":"12",
                     "retailSubDepartment":"123",
                     "retailClass":"12309",
                     "retailSubClass":"1230930"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "headers":{
      "X_INSTANA_L_S":"1",
      "X_INSTANA_T":"0000000000000000553d86df527194d5",
      "X_INSTANA_S":"87cb409133490aa9"
   }
}`

and my expetced output is `[
    {
        "eventTime": "2024-01-17T15:10:06.858",
        "groupArticleNumber": "GI7343",
        "sourcingSizeCode3": "190",
        "productDescEN": "A.RDY UPF LS P",
        "colorwayShortDescEN": "NHLSJS/WHTMEL/BLACK",
        "keyCategory": "00056",
        "groupModelNumber": "FRX88",
        "productDescriptionEN": "ESTRO 19 JSYY",
        "retailClass": "12309",
        "retailSubClass": "1230930",
        "retailDepartment": "12",
        "retailSubDepartment": "123",
        "rmhProductDivision": "2",
        "subBrand": "1",
        "brand": "11",
        "rmhCategory": "09",
        "businessSegment": "104",
        "ageGroup": "J",
        "gender": "M",
        "genderAge": "16",
        "genderAgeMain": "Kids",
        "articleLifeCycle": "50",
        "sizePage": "J4",
        "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC",
        "mainMaterialFlag": true,
        "articleCreationSeason": "20201",
        "articleActiveSeason": "20242",
        "salesLine": "L84",
        "rmhProductType": "30"
    },
    {
        "eventTime": "2024-01-17T15:10:06.858",
        "groupArticleNumber": "GI7343",
        "sourcingSizeCode3": "180",
        "productDescEN": "A.RDY UPF LS P",
        "colorwayShortDescEN": "NHLSJS/WHTMEL/BLACK",
        "keyCategory": "00056",
        "groupModelNumber": "FRX88",
        "productDescriptionEN": "ESTRO 19 JSYY",
        "retailClass": "12309",
        "retailSubClass": "1230930",
        "retailDepartment": "12",
        "retailSubDepartment": "123",
        "rmhProductDivision": "2",
        "subBrand": "1",
        "brand": "11",
        "rmhCategory": "09",
        "businessSegment": "104",
        "ageGroup": "J",
        "gender": "M",
        "genderAge": "16",
        "genderAgeMain": "Kids",
        "articleLifeCycle": "50",
        "sizePage": "J4",
        "materialComposition": "100% PET-REC",
        "mainMaterialFlag": true,
        "articleCreationSeason": "20201",
        "articleActiveSeason": "20242",
        "salesLine": "L84",
        "rmhProductType": "30"
    },
    {
        "eventTime": "2024-01-17T15:10:06.858",
        "groupArticleNumber": "GI7343",
        "sourcingSizeCode3": "190",
        "productDescEN": "A.RDY UPF LS P",
        "colorwayShortDescEN": "NHLSJS/WHTMEL/BLACK",
        "keyCategory": "00056",
        "groupModelNumber": "FRX88",
        "productDescriptionEN": "ESTRO 19 JSYY",
        "retailClass": "12309",
        "retailSubClass": "1230930",
        "retailDepartment": "12",
        "retailSubDepartment": "123",
        "rmhProductDivision": "2",
        "subBrand": "1",
        "brand": "11",
        "rmhCategory": "09",
        "businessSegment": "104",
        "ageGroup": "J",
        "gender": "M",
        "genderAge": "16",
        "genderAgeMain": "Kids",
        "articleLifeCycle": "50",
        "sizePage": "J4",
         "materialComposition":"100% PET-DAT",
        "mainMaterialFlag": false,
        "articleCreationSeason": "20201",
        "articleActiveSeason": "20242",
        "salesLine": "L84",
        "rmhProductType": "30"
    },
    {
        "eventTime": "2024-01-17T15:10:06.858",
        "groupArticleNumber": "GI7343",
        "sourcingSizeCode3": "180",
        "productDescEN": "A.RDY UPF LS P",
        "colorwayShortDescEN": "NHLSJS/WHTMEL/BLACK",
        "keyCategory": "00056",
        "groupModelNumber": "FRX88",
        "productDescriptionEN": "ESTRO 19 JSYY",
        "retailClass": "12309",
        "retailSubClass": "1230930",
        "retailDepartment": "12",
        "retailSubDepartment": "123",
        "rmhProductDivision": "2",
        "subBrand": "1",
        "brand": "11",
        "rmhCategory": "09",
        "businessSegment": "104",
        "ageGroup": "J",
        "gender": "M",
        "genderAge": "16",
        "genderAgeMain": "Kids",
        "articleLifeCycle": "50",
        "sizePage": "J4",
         "materialComposition":"100% PET-DAT",
        "mainMaterialFlag": false,
        "articleCreationSeason": "20201",
        "articleActiveSeason": "20242",
        "salesLine": "L84",
        "rmhProductType": "30"
    }
]`
```

For this i want the jolt spec so tried spec and got the above Json .and then tried your solution it is getting expected output,

But can you do this in one step??

Comment: *can you do this in one step??** -> Short answer is **No, we can't** . Since, mutually multiplexing of the array components, and besides reversing them of one of the arrays are needed. Those are the costs of which we have to deal with while preventing hard-coding, all needed to be evaluated atomically within their logical space.